# Changing part of a composite-id

Tags: nhibernate, many-to-many

I have a class, BillMedicine, which is many-to-many table for Bill and Medicine.
The BillMedicine mapping file is:

```
<class name="BillMedicine" table="Bill_Medicine">
    <composite-id>
        <key-many-to-one name="Bill" class="Bill" column="BillID" />
        <key-many-to-one name="Medicine" class="Medicine" column="MedicineID" />
    </composite-id>
    <version name="LastModifiedOn" column="LastModifiedOn" type="DateTime" 
             access="field.pascalcase-underscore" />
    <property name="Quantity" column="QuantityPurchased" />
</class>
```

When I create a new BillMedicine and update the quantity my unit test succeeds. However if I uncomment the line that updates the medicine, I got the exception `NHibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction`

```
BillMedicineRepository target = new BillMedicineRepository();
BillMedicine billMedicine =
    new BillMedicine { Bill = _bill, Medicine = _medicine1, Quantity = 1 };
target.AddBillMedicine(billMedicine);

//billMedicine.Medicine = _medicine2;
billMedicine.Quantity = 2;
target.UpdateBillMedicine(billMedicine); // Exception if I update the medicine
```

I have checked the SQL shown by NHibernate and it is not updating the medicine

```
UPDATE Bill_Medicine SET LastModifiedOn = @p0, QuantityPurchased = @p1
WHERE BillID = @p2 AND MedicineID = @p3 AND LastModifiedOn = @p4;
```

**Edit:**

My Questions:
1- Why updating the quantity only is working but updating the medicine is throwing exception?
2- Is it possible to make Nhibernate update the medicine property? If yes, how? If no, can someone suggest a workaround?

Comment: Note that the qurey generated by NHibernate for UpdateBillMedicine is not updating the MedicineID, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NHibernate does not allow changing the primary key.

Possible workarounds:

- Create a new instance with the new medicine and delete the old one
- Use an [HQL update](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#batch-direct) to change the Medicine. Keep in mind that the in-memory state won't match the DB unless you `Evict` the instance and load it again.

Comment: How can I get the old medicine ID? Let's say that I have already changed the medicine property, can I get the old medicien?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create another object, because i have a deja-vu here. Your trying to

1. create an object with the key B1 M1
2. save it
3. keeping the same object and same
   reference, changing the key to B1 M2
4. updating the new object (with an old
   reference)

I'd recommend either `flushing your session` between the save and the update, or `using a transaction` for each of the operations (flushing should be enough though, i recommend the transaction only because it's a good practice :) ). I have the feeling you're trying to update an object that hasn't been inserted yet

Comment: In AddBillMedicine and UpdateBillMedicine, I am saving/updating using a new transaction. I have also tried to add session.Flush but in vain. The point is if I update the quantity only the update succeeds however if I update the medicine the update fails.

Comment: Also I am not updating a new obejct, I am updating the object I have just saved.

Comment: sh_kamath: it's a new object in the sense that its key is different. In a database like this B1M1 and B1M2 should be different objects

Comment: If you consider the primary keys of the table then your comment correct. But the query generated by NHibernate is updating the Bill_Medicine table so it seems that NHibernate is aware that this object is already inserted in the database.